# UIWebView with dynamic height leads to memory crash

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, memory, uiwebview

I've a native iOS screen with `UITableView` inside that displays some article. Some cells in this table display article image, title, author, comments, etc. But there is a single cell with `UIWebView` inside that displays article content. This cell has dynamic height depending on the content size. Article content goes from the server as html string in JSON response and may contain images, videos and other things that supports HTML format. I can edit this string using regular expressions depending on some requirements (for example increase font size depending on app settings). Here is an image representing my UI structure:
[image]

The problem is that once the article content is very large, `UITableView` cell with `UIWebView` inside becomes also very large in height and this leads to memory crash. In my case this crash happens only on iPhone 6 Plus. On all of the other devices including iPhone (5, 5S, 6), iPad (2, 3, 4) (and probably other devices that supports iOS 7) app works correctly. As I suspect the reason is that iPhone 6 Plus has a high resolution screen and only 1 Gb of memory. So rendering the same content with the same amount of memory as in other devices, but in larger resolution, leads to memory crash.

I've created two test applications with UI as in the image below:

[image]

Both apps load the same HTML content in a single `UIWebView`. There is no other ui or logic in both apps.

In case a) all works correctly, scroll indicator appears and only visible content are rendered. When I'm scrolling fast, I can see white space that after a moment replaces with rendered content.

In case b) `UIWebView` stretches to fit content size. Test app is crashes (as my real app). As I suspect in this case even invisible content rendered and that leads to memory crash.

**So my question is:**
How can I fix this bug without scrolling inside `UIWebView`? Only `UITableView` should be scrollable

Comment: You ever figure this out? I am running into the same issue.

Comment: I'm also facing this problem. Did you solve it? Thanks.

Comment: I solved this problem by restricting maximum height for web view cell. If web view cell height is more than certain amount of pixels, instead of increasing its height I show "Show more..." button. When user taps on this button, fullscreen UIWebView presented without additional UI elements and user can scroll only UIWebView content. I don't like this solution, but this is the only solution I've found. In my case this was approved by customers.

Answer (score 1):

Make your UITableViewCell reusable. i-e`(UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];)`.
one thing very important don't use `[UIimage imagenamed:@"Imagename.jpg"]` which leads you to a memory crash, you can use `[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Imagename" ofType:@"png"]];`. 
I hope it might help.

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. My `UITableViewCell`s already reusable.
My test app also crashes. It doesn't have any `UIImage`s and `UITableView`. Only single `UIWebView`

Comment: And what about image loading?

Comment: Edited my previous comment with answer about images

Answer (score 0):

You can give webview constant height. it has scrollviewer inside. otherwise it is really hard to render large content at once. if you give webview constant size(max value) white spaces will be removed too.

edit: webviews own scrollview should work fine with tableviews scrollview bu i am not sure

Comment: I already tried that. In this case `UIWebView` scrolled separately from containing `UITableView`. I need a single scroll for this screen, not scroll view inside another scroll view

Comment: i don't have my mac near by. can you try WKWebView for iphone 6+. it supports only ios8+ but iphone6 is also only available for ios8+. maybe can give better performance.

Comment: I just tried such approach, but unfortunately result is the same - app crashes with very large html content

Comment: in that case if there wasn't any other solution you can try to find a way to work with 2 scrollviews. it looks like certain solution for memory management. Good luck!